# An entry with the same key already exists, but no duplicates in resources present

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

After returning from the holidays, I get the same error message as in the title:

> An entry with the same key already exists.

The error points to this line:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPersDesc" Text="Placeholder irrelevant" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="lblPersDesc"/>
```

If I comment this line out, the error appears on the next element with a `meta:resourceKey` property.

Taken steps to rectify:

- Check markup for duplicate Ids
- Check database table for duplicate resource Keys
- Clear & Rebuild solution
- force recompile of the .aspx page
- clear resourceProvider cache

Where could the error be located and what could I have been missing?

EDIT: More page markup.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/.../...cs" Inherits="..." Title="..." %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cont" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037182/system-argumentexception-an-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists

Comment: Amit, I have already checked all similar questions on SO, and I even tried the answer in your marked question, although the problems don't seem to be related. Didn't work

Comment: What stack trace says?

Comment: There is no stack trace, it does not compile anymore.

Comment: Need to check complete page markup then. What is your page directive?

Comment: I have truncated and refilled my resources, with the commit from one day before my holidays and I compiles again. I have lost a few hours of work, which needs to be redone, but I guess its better then guessing in the wild now and probably lose an undefined amount of hours in the process

Comment: Ok. If that is working then suggest to check difference between two versions whenever you get time.