# System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists - c# ClentIDMode

Tags: c#, asp.net

When deploying my website on a server , I found ID of some div using in master page is changing with a prefix "ctl00". So that UI is getting misaligned.

By searching I have found that need to set ClientIDMode to static in web.config file.

```
   <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static" />
```

Now, that ID issue is resolved. But when clicking on rows of grid view, throws an error

> System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.

Strangely, this exception throws on a javascript that I'm calling only on a button click (not calling inside gridview). Can anyone explain why this is happens?

```
    function Show_Hide_Display() {            
       if (document.getElementById("<%=fade.ClientID%>").style.display == "" || document.getElementById("<%=fade.ClientID%>").style.display == "block") {
             document.getElementById("<%=fade.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
         }
         else {
             document.getElementById("<%=fade.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
         }
         return false;
     }
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037182/system-argumentexception-an-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists). Which says to set clientIDMode as predictable. Is this enough to solve this issue? Or need to set separate clientIDMode for gridview?

Comment: So you're saying that you're getting a .NET exception on a piece of Javascript that doesn't call back to your ASP.NET code?

Comment: Does row click cause a post-back? How about sharing the reproducible code?

Comment: When setting clientIDMode ="Predictable" on Gridview this error is not coming

Comment: Is it possible that the row click posts back and you are re-filling the grid with the same rows? `if(!IsPostBack) { FillTheGrid(); }` is the usual way (I assume viewstate is enabled). Are you doing this?

Comment: Do you use a template to fill the grid? Please share full page code (aspx and aspx.cs)

Comment: @OguzOzgul  yes. It happens when I'm clciking on edit column of gridview

Comment: yes doing if(!IsPostBack) { FillTheGrid(); }

Comment: Are you going to share the source code? My browser tab is about to be closed.

Comment: Don't use static clientIDMode. Especially in GridView, Repeater etc.

Comment: Now I'm using    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static" /> on web.config And on gridview, set clientIDMode="Predictable" . Now that issue is solved. Is this the correct way ?